# how to level image color histogram using python like on photoshop

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation

I need to achieve using python the same that I can do using Photoshop from menu: "Image > Adjustments > Levels..."

As on this window:

[image: Photoshop Levels]

I need to level the color using Python to the first value to 13.

[image: Photoshop Levels - Value 13]

Can this be done using some library image-scikit, opencv, numpy or something ?

I have been seen several auto balance and auto contrast, etc, but I need to modify just that value on several images.

Thanks.

Comment: What??? On hold because is "too broad"? I ask specifically how to do just one image manipulation and how to achive it on python... Why on earth you consider that as "too broad"?!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, then you are taking the RBG values and setting all of the values that are below the minimum threshold and setting them equal to the minimum threshold? If that is the case then we can just load the image with opencv as a numpy array and use array operations to achieve the same result.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

min_level = 20

#im = cv2.imread("name.jpg") # loads image as np array
im = np.arange(75.).reshape(5, 5, 3) # pretend image to show filtering 
im[im < min_level] = min_level # set all indices where value is less than min_level to min_level
```

so before the filtering we have an array that looks like:

```
>>> im
[[[ 0.  1.  2.]
  [ 3.  4.  5.]
  [ 6.  7.  8.]
  [ 9. 10. 11.]
  [12. 13. 14.]]

 [[15. 16. 17.]
  [18. 19. 20.]
  [21. 22. 23.]
  [24. 25. 26.]
  [27. 28. 29.]]

 [[30. 31. 32.]
  [33. 34. 35.]
  [36. 37. 38.]
  [39. 40. 41.]
  [42. 43. 44.]]

 [[45. 46. 47.]
  [48. 49. 50.]
  [51. 52. 53.]
  [54. 55. 56.]
  [57. 58. 59.]]

 [[60. 61. 62.]
  [63. 64. 65.]
  [66. 67. 68.]
  [69. 70. 71.]
  [72. 73. 74.]]]
```

and after the filtering it looks like:

```
>>> im
[[[20. 20. 20.]
  [20. 20. 20.]
  [20. 20. 20.]
  [20. 20. 20.]
  [20. 20. 20.]]

 [[20. 20. 20.]
  [20. 20. 20.]
  [21. 22. 23.]
  [24. 25. 26.]
  [27. 28. 29.]]

 [[30. 31. 32.]
  [33. 34. 35.]
  [36. 37. 38.]
  [39. 40. 41.]
  [42. 43. 44.]]

 [[45. 46. 47.]
  [48. 49. 50.]
  [51. 52. 53.]
  [54. 55. 56.]
  [57. 58. 59.]]
```

Comment: No, I tried that just now, but that makes the image lighter, and when I do that in photoshop the image tend to be darker. I tried the below "output level" and does that, makes it darker, so probably it is changing the output levels. or changing the input levels but no the below threshold, the upper threshold (the value from the right)

Comment: Im just not sure what photoshop does in the problem. You can use this same technique to filter the top end of the image too. You can also normalize the data instead of that's what is needed

Comment: Hi Grant, I just do: `max_level = 255 - level; new_image[new_image > max_level] = max_level` and so far it seems to do the job.

Comment: ah i see. glad you got it working!

Comment: Do you know another method to do the same? I think that there is some "data loss"

Comment: are you trying to normalize the data in a range? You have to let me know what the function is supposed to do exactly and ill help